# Doubly Circular Linked List

Tags: java, list, distance, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I created a Doubly Circular Linked List.

I need to know the distance from every node to head.

Because when I must delete or get a node with a specific key, if 2 nodes have the same key and same distance, both must be deleted or got, otherwise must be deleted the node closest to head.

I don't know how to calculate the distance because is circular ...

The insertion of this Linked List work in this way.

All the nodes go after the Head.

Example :

1) Head

2) Head-A (Inserted A)

3) Head-B-A (Inserted B)

4) Head-C-B-A (Inserted C)

For now, i did only a normal cancellation without the distance.
This is my code.

```
/* Function to delete node with the key  */
public void deleteWithKey(int key) {
    if (key == head.getData()) {
        if (size == 1) {
            head = null;
            end = null;
            size = 0;
            return;
        }
        head = head.getLinkNext();
        head.setLinkPrev(end);
        end.setLinkNext(head);
        size--;
        return;
    }
    if (key == end.getData()) {
        end = end.getLinkPrev();
        end.setLinkNext(head);
        head.setLinkPrev(end);
        size--;
    }
    Node current = head.getLinkNext();
    for (int i = 2; i < size; i++) {
        if (key == current.getData()) {
            Node p = current.getLinkPrev();
            Node n = current.getLinkNext();

            p.setLinkNext(n);
            n.setLinkPrev(p);
            size--;
            return;
        }
        current = current.getLinkNext();
    }
    System.out.println("Don't exist a node with this key");
}
```

Thanks to All.

Comment: Why is it a problem to calculate the distance?

Comment: Because is circular. Every node is linked to right and left. I need to know the distance from the head to every node.

Comment: Example : I have a list Head-B-A , B and A have the same distance. Because A is linked to Head.    Would be A<-->Head<-->B<--->A

Comment: Other example : Head-D-C-B-A .  C and B have the same distance because Head-D-C (Distance 2).  B-A-Head (Distance 2)

Comment: i think u missed "end" node between "head" and "A"

Comment: If you have the distance in one direction and the total length of the list, it is easy to calculate the distance in the other direction. You can take the shorter of the two.

Comment: @ShaurabhBharti The end is A. See the insertion mode.

Comment: @Henry I did 2 functions. They are at the bottom.

Comment: You need just one of them and the total length: distb = length - dista

Comment: @Master-Antonio A's next should point to an empty node "end", just like B's previous points to an empty node "head". If you don't maintain empty nodes like this, then you should, as it is recommended for linked lists (avoids unnecessary end node checks, see my code below, it does not need to check for any end cases)

Comment: @ShaurabhBharti A is liked to Head because is a Circular Doubly Linked List. The head is the first node inserted, the end will always be the second node inserted (The text of the project says so.). Because every node is inserted after the head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final working code that i did.

Have you improvements?

Thanks to all for the help.

Complexity = O(n)

```
/* Function to delete node with the key */
public void deleteWithKey(int key) {
    if (key == head.getData()) {
        if (size == 1) {
            head = null;
            end = null;
            size = 0;
            return;
        }
        head = head.getLinkNext();
        head.setLinkPrev(end);
        end.setLinkNext(head);
        size--;
        return;
    }
    if (key == end.getData()) {
        end = end.getLinkPrev();
        end.setLinkNext(head);
        head.setLinkPrev(end);
        size--;
    }
    Node next = head;
    Node back = head;
    while (next != end) {
        next = next.getLinkNext();
        back = back.getLinkPrev();
        if ((key == next.getData()) && (key == back.getData()) && (next != back)) {
            Node p = next.getLinkPrev();
            Node n = next.getLinkNext();
            Node p1 = back.getLinkPrev();
            Node n1 = next.getLinkNext();
            p.setLinkNext(n);
            n.setLinkPrev(p);
            p1.setLinkPrev(n1);
            n1.setLinkPrev(p1);
            size -= 2;
            return;
        }

        if ((key == next.getData()) && (next != back)) {
            Node p = next.getLinkPrev();
            Node n = next.getLinkNext();
            p.setLinkNext(n);
            n.setLinkPrev(p);
            size--;
            return;
        }
        if ((key == next.getData()) && (next == back)) {
            Node p = next.getLinkPrev();
            Node n = next.getLinkNext();
            p.setLinkNext(n);
            n.setLinkPrev(p);
            size--;
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Don't exist a node with this key");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to know the distance. Rather, you need to *find the closest to head*.

Since it's a circular doubly linked list, this task is trivial:

1. define two variables `a` and `b`, initializing both to head
2. if either are the target, remove matching nodes and exit
3. assign `a = a.next` and `b = b.previous`
4. goto 2

Comment: Right. I did not think about it . I like this solution. I test fast.

Answer (score 0):

This is the pseudocode I could think of to solve the problem.

Given `head`,

```
// no data
if(head==null) return;
// next and prev are always at same distance
next = head;
prev = head.prev;

// ensure nodes are not same or crossed half way through the list
while (next == prev || next.prev == prev){
// delete nodes if values are same
if (next.val == prev.val){
    if(next!=head) {
        next.prev.next = next.next;
        next.next.prev = next.prev;
        prev.prev.next = prev.next;
        prev.next.prev = prev.prev;
    }
    // list has only two nodes
    else if(head.next==prev){
        head = null;
        return;
    // remove head and its prev node
    else{
        head = head.next;
        head.prev = prev.next;
        head.prev.next = head
    }
}
// traverse through the list
next = next.next
prev = prev.prev
}
```

Comment: the next and prev parameters of the class Node helps us scroll through nodes

Comment: (The text of the project) says that the head is the first node inserted and the end will always be the second node inserted for the insertion mode.

Comment: they are data nodes. you should keep two empty pointers to these data nodes to simply your impl code

Comment: i have updated the code as you are trying to impl it.. see how complex the code looks now!!

Comment: you should not keep any vars except "head". its a trivial prob anyways.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145308/discussion-between-master-antonio-and-shaurabh-bharti).

Comment: The code is wrong. Else state is out the Else If or in?